# video player caption not enable after set caption file

Tags: jquery, html5-video, plyr.js

I am using https://plyr.io/ to have a video player with captions. (Documentation: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr).

Below is the steps to reproduce caption issue with video player with example code:

In the page load initialize the video player in jquery document load.

```html
<video controls
       crossorigin
       playsinline
       id="player">
</video>
```

inside jquery page load:

```js
 const video = document.querySelector('video');
     const player = new Plyr(video, {
        captions: {active:false},
    });
```

3. After page load upload the .mp4 file and set to the video player like below:

```js
 player.source = {
            type: 'video',
            title: mvFileName,
            sources: [
                {
                    src: mvUrl,
                    type: mvfileContentType,
                    size: 720,
                }
            ],
            poster: posterPath,
        };
```

Till here i could able to set the .mp4 file to the video and it is playing the video fine.

3. Then i upload the subtitle file(.vtt) and set to this video player like below:

```js
const track = document.createElement('track');
        Object.assign(track, {
            kind: "captions",
            label: $('#hdnMVSubttleLangName').val(),
            srclang: $('#hdnMVSubttleShortLang').val(),
            src: jsonResponse.SubtitleUrl,
        });
        player.media.appendChild(track);
```

After this code when i inspect the video i could find like the track tag set inside the video tag with subtitle path like below:

```html
<video crossorigin="" data-poster="/Content/Movies/MoviePoster/47eb9kRPz4g=MV.png" playsinline="" src="/Content/Movies/47eb9kRPz4g=MV.mp4"><source src="/Content/Movies/47eb9kRPz4g=MV.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="720">
<track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="/Content/Movies/MovieSubtitle/vdoSubtle.vtt">

</video>
```

After setting subtitle just after used below code to make the caption active:

```js
player.captions.active = true;
```

Issue: Now in the video caption icon not enabled, Also in settings, I could see caption option available.

Also, Please suggest your best approach, If in above used any code is wrong.

Need help